# How to pass object data type to class or function?

Tags: android, kotlin

The result of this code is what I want :

```
override fun onResponse(call:Call<MainResp<ItemMaterial>>,response:Response<MainResp<ItemMaterial>>){
    val arawjson: String = Gson().toJson(response.body())
    val dataType = object : TypeToken<MainResp<ItemMaterial>>() {}.type
    val mainResp: MainResp<ItemMaterial> = Gson().fromJson<MainResp<ItemMaterial>>(arawjson, dataType)
 ........

}
```

But when I make it simple class so I can access every function with object data type parameter.

```
class Convert<T>{
    //fungsi umum untuk konversi gson sesuai dengan output datatype sebagai parameter yakni T
    fun convertRespByType(response: Response<MainResp<T>>): MainResp<T> {
        val arawjson: String = Gson().toJson(response.body())

        val dataType = object : TypeToken<MainResp<T>>() {}.type
        val mainResp: MainResp<T> = Gson().fromJson<MainResp<T>>(arawjson, dataType)
        return mainResp
    }
}
```

And call it :

```
override fun onResponse(call:Call<MainResp<ItemMaterial>>,response:Response<MainResp<ItemMaterial>>){
        val aconvert : Convert <ItemMaterial> = Convert()
        val mainResp : MainResp<ItemMaterial> = aconvert.convertRespByType(response)
     ........

    }
```

But the second result which I call with the class is different with the first one ?
I think the parameter not passing to the class. Can you give me a recommedation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

In the statement `TypeToken<MainResp<T>>()` the type `T` is not available at runtime.

In Kotlin you could use [inline reified](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) to solve your problem. Reified does only work with functions and not with classes:

```
inline fun <reified T> convertRespByType(response: Response<MainResp<T>>): MainResp<T> {
    val arawjson: String = Gson().toJson(response.body())

    val dataType = object : TypeToken<MainResp<T>>() {}.type
    val mainResp: MainResp<T> = Gson().fromJson<MainResp<T>>(arawjson, dataType)
    return mainResp
}
```

Usage:

```
val mainResp = convertRespByType<ItemMaterial>(response)
```

Comment: Thanks for your great response, I have tried your solution but the datatype "itemMaterial" still not passing to the function.

the return "LinkedTreeMap" Data type. In addition when I use 
val mainResp = convertRespByType<ItemMaterial>(response). 

ItemMaterial show warning : this inspection reports function calls with type arguments that can be safely removed and inferred

Comment: @rizkidzulkarnain You could check (via `println` or debugger) if the `datatype` correctly contains the generic `ItemMaterial`-type. I verified this with a simpler example and it works. If the  variable `datatype`  contains the correct type and it still not works as expected, then you have another issue. The warning is, because the compiler can infer the correct type for the generic function. I specified the type in the answer for a better understanding. You can safely remove the type.

Comment: I already debugged **datatype** variable value and the value is **MainResp<T>** if I using the first one in my question **MainResp<ItemMaterial>** I think the parameter still not passing. Have you try this methode and work in your side ?

Comment: In my example https://gist.github.com/rpreissel/b83091dc6fef3610fc989d561be97022 it works.